# Union all customers from two tables and assign date values from second table in case customer does not exist in first table

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d29496787a0b60a3420cc048ba281806)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales 
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    last_order DATE,
    customer VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO sales (last_order, customer)
VALUES 
('2020-09-10', 'user_01'),
('2020-10-15', 'user_02'),
('2020-11-26', 'user_03');


CREATE TABLE customers 
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    first_order DATE,
    customer VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO customers (first_order, customer)
VALUES 
('2020-08-10', 'user_01'),
('2020-09-15', 'user_02'),
('2020-10-17', 'user_03'),
('2020-05-03', 'user_04'),
('2020-04-12', 'user_05');
```

Expected result:

```
customer   |   used_date    |
-----------|----------------|------
user_01    |   2020-09-10   |
user_02    |   2020-10-15   |
user_03    |   2020-11-26   |
user_04    |   2020-05-03   |
user_05    |   2020-04-12   |
```

I have two tables and I want to query all customers in both tables.

Additionally, in case the customer does not exist in the table `sales` I want to apply the `first_order` from table `customers` as `used_date`.

So far I came up with this query:

```
SELECT
    t1.customer,
    (CASE WHEN t1.last_order IS NULL THEN t1.first_order ELSE t1.last_order END) AS used_date
FROM
   (SELECT
        s.customer,
        s.last_order AS last_order,
        NULL::date AS first_order
    FROM 
        sales s
    GROUP BY 
        1, 2, 3

    UNION ALL
 
    SELECT
        c.customer,
        NULL::date AS last_order,
        c.first_order AS first_order
    FROM 
        customers c
    GROUP BY 
        1, 2, 3) t1
GROUP BY 
    1, 2
ORDER BY 
    1;
```

How do I need to modify the `CASE WHEN` statement to get the expected result?

Comment: 1. Is it possible that customer detail is present in sales table but not in customer table. 2. Is it possible that sales table is having multiple entry against customer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a `left join`:

```
select c.*, 
       coalesce(s.last_order, c.first_order) as used_date
from customers c left join
     sales s
     on c.customer = s.customer;
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2b1303acc51603199f0c8a606895b9a3

Comment: Just for my documenation: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=97a8afc827f9e6028c35451b4564ba04